# How does xargs format the input of $'\n'?

Tags: bash, pipe, echo, newline, xargs

## Problem

**(1)** Given a string, I replace spaces with `$'\n'` using `sed`:

```
echo "one two" | sed 's/ /$'"'"'\\n'"'"'/g'
```

This outputs:

```
# one$'\n'two
```

**(2)** Note that echoing this output of (1):

```
echo one$'\n'two
```

results in:

```
# one
# two
```

**(3)** I echo the output of (1) in another way, by piping the output of (1) into `xargs echo`:

```
echo "one two" | sed 's/ /$'"'"'\\n'"'"'/g' | xargs echo
```

But I don't get the same output as (2):

```
# one$\ntwo
```

## Question

What does `xargs` do when formatting the input of a string containing `$'\n'`?

Why is echoing a string with `$'\n'` not the same as using `xargs echo` on the same string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write

```
echo one$'\n'two
```

at the command line, bash replaces the "$'\n'" with a newline. But when you pass it to `xargs` no such replacement can happen.

But piping it to `xargs` will *still* not do what you want, since by default `xargs` uses the newline as an argument separator:

```
$ echo "one two" | tr ' ' '\n' | xargs echo
one two
```

You must tell `xargs` to use a different separator, even if it is a bogus one:

```
$ echo "one two" | tr ' ' '\n' | xargs -0 echo
one
two
```

Answer (score 0):

Unsure if answering your question, but a trick I've used in the past for similar cases is to use `printf` instead, which loops over passed arguments in a loop (if not enough `%` to consume them), e.g.:

```
$ printf "%s\n" one two
one
two
```

Use shell own white-space separator if above are in a single string

```
$ args="one two"
$ printf "%s\n" $args
one
two
```

Just for completeness, feed to `xargs -n1` with some *foo* scriptlet

```
$ printf "%s\n" one two |xargs -n1 sh -c 'echo [$(date -R)] foo=$1' --
[Sun, 03 Jun 2018 21:34:17 -0300] foo=one
[Sun, 03 Jun 2018 21:34:17 -0300] foo=two
```